# Multidimensional array undefined index issue

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a code which am working on and unable to understand how do i bypass it for the null value

```
for ( $k = 0; $k < count( $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ] ); $k++ ) {
    if ( in_array( $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['starttime'], $hours ) ) {

    $iva_departments[$iva_all_dpt_info[$weekdays[$j]][$k]['title']]['doctors_id'][] = isset($iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[$j]][$k]['doctor_id'])?$iva_departments[ $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['title'] ]['doctors_id'][] = $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[$j]][$k]['doctor_id']:$iva_departments[ $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['title'] ]['doctors_id'][] = '';

    $iva_departments[$iva_all_dpt_info[$weekdays[$j]][$k]['title']]['doctors'][] = isset($iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[$j]][$k]['doctors'])?$iva_departments[ $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['title'] ]['doctors'][] = $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[$j]][$k]['doctors']:$iva_departments[ $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['title'] ]['doctors'][] = '';

    $iva_departments[$iva_all_dpt_info[$weekdays[$j]][$k]['title']]['department'][] = isset($iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[$j]][$k]['department'])?$iva_departments[ $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['title'] ]['department'][] = $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[$j]][$k]['department']:$iva_departments[ $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['title'] ]['department'][] = '';

    $iva_departments[$iva_all_dpt_info[$weekdays[$j]][$k]['title']]['specialty'][] = isset($iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[$j]][$k]['specialty'])?$iva_departments[ $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['title'] ]['specialty'][] = $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[$j]][$k]['specialty']:$iva_departments[ $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['title'] ]['specialty'][] = '';

        // if timeformat is 12 hours
        if ( $iva_timeformat == 12 ) {
            $iva_departments[ $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['title'] ]['hours'][] = date( 'h.i a', strtotime( $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['starttime'] ) ) . ' - ' . date( 'h.i a', strtotime( $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['endtime'] ) );
        } else {
            $iva_departments[ $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['title'] ]['hours'][]      = $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['starttime'] . ' - ' . $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['endtime'];
        }

    }
}
```

Not sure about how to use isset for the `title` index. How can I use the isset in it.

Comment: `if (isset($iva_departments[ $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['title'] ]))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
for ( $k = 0; $k < count( $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ] ); $k++ ) {
  if ( in_array( $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['starttime'], $hours ) ) {
    if(isset($iva_departments[ $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['title'] ])){
       $iva_departments[ $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['title'] ]['doctors_id'][] = $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[$j]][$k]['doctor_id'];
       $iva_departments[ $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['title'] ]['doctors'][] = $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['doctor'];
       $iva_departments[ $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['title'] ]['department'][] = $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ]][$k]['department'];
       $iva_departments[ $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['title'] ]['specialty'][] = $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ]][$k]['specialty'];

      // if timeformat is 12 hours
      if ( $iva_timeformat == 12 ) {
           $iva_departments[ $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['title'] ]['hours'][] = date( 'h.i a', strtotime( $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['starttime'] ) ) . ' - ' . date( 'h.i a', strtotime( $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['endtime'] ) );
      } else {
           $iva_departments[ $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['title'] ]['hours'][]      = $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['starttime'] . ' - ' . $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['endtime'];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Add isset in these above lines too.
$iva_departments[ $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['title'] ]['doctors_id'][] = $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[$j]][$k]['doctor_id'];

Comment: @Maqk check the code. i have edit it. Now there is no error for title undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I will give an example of what you can do: So you want to check if the data that you want to insert in each of the nested fields of `title` array exists. What you can do then is:

```
for ( $k = 0; $k < count( $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ] ); $k++ ) {
    if ( in_array( $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['starttime'], $hours ) ) {

       isset($iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[$j]][$k]['doctor_id'])?$iva_departments[ $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['title'] ]['doctors_id'][] = $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[$j]][$k]['doctor_id']:$iva_departments[ $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['title'] ]['doctors_id'][] = '';

       isset($iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[$j]][$k]['doctors'])?$iva_departments[ $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['title'] ]['doctors'][] = $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[$j]][$k]['doctors']:$iva_departments[ $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['title'] ]['doctors'][] = '';

       isset($iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[$j]][$k]['department'])?$iva_departments[ $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['title'] ]['department'][] = $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[$j]][$k]['department']:$iva_departments[ $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['title'] ]['department'][] = '';

       isset($iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[$j]][$k]['specialty'])?$iva_departments[ $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['title'] ]['specialty'][] = $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[$j]][$k]['specialty']:$iva_departments[ $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['title'] ]['specialty'][] = '';

        // if timeformat is 12 hours
        if ( $iva_timeformat == 12 ) {
            $iva_departments[ $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['title'] ]['hours'][] = date( 'h.i a', strtotime( $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['starttime'] ) ) . ' - ' . date( 'h.i a', strtotime( $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['endtime'] ) );
        } else {
            $iva_departments[ $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['title'] ]['hours'][]      = $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['starttime'] . ' - ' . $iva_all_dpt_info[ $weekdays[ $j ] ][ $k ]['endtime'];
        }

    }
}
```

So this will check if the value you try to assign to your field exists and if not it will just put an empty string.

Comment: Which line throws the error? Can you paste it here? Also my solution is just 1 example. You should do this for every line.

Comment: You got it wrong. remove completely the part:

 `$iva_departments[$iva_all_dpt_info[$weekdays[$j]][$k]['title']]['doctors_id'][] = `


And all that are similar to it of course.
This is what the ternary will do , check if it is set and assign values based on that. It's like an if-else.

I updated my answer to fit the code you updated.